# Is there something like Vuex for Svelte 3?

Tags: state, vuex, store, svelte, svelte-3

**Is there something like Vuex for Svelte 3?**

Since I am tired of using GraphQL and want to go back to using classic REST API I would like something to help me in the browser just as the Apollo cache-store has helped me so far.

Especially for persisting in the browser between one session and another of the user.

Comment: https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store

Comment: @2pha thanks but it's not quite the same! LOL

Comment: what about https://github.com/timhall/svelte-apollo ?